# Bean not found error : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the below Main App:-

Both packages are in different module and i have "com.app.api is included in the pom.xml of com.app.batch

```
    //commented  @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.app.batch", "com.app.api"})
        public class App 
        {
            public static void main( String[] args )
            {

                 SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
            }
        }
```

In `com.app.api` i have class `ApiClass`

```
@Service
public class ApiClass {}
```

in `com.app.batch i have

```
@Component
public class JobRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        apiClass.getData(1111);
    }
}
```

When i comment `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.app.batch", "com.app.api"})` i get the following error

> Field apiClass in com.app.batch.config.JobRunner required a bean of
>   type 'com.com.api.ApiClass' that could not be found.

How can i resolve the issue without using `scanBasePackages` .I don't want to use `scanBasePackages` as the module can get added in future and it can get cumberson

Comment: You need to only remove scanBasePackages={"com.app.batch", "com.app.api"} instead of whole @SpringBootApplication(...). Keep @SpringBootApplication and try

Comment: Your App class needs to be in com.app - which will automatically act like a base package and all the packages inside will be scanned by SpringBootApplication annotation. If you do not wish to change the package of App class then scanBasePackages is one of the better ways to do it. But I would suggest if possible change the package of App class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your not interested to use

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.app.batch", "com.app.api"})
```

you need to change the package hierarchy so that spring scans the beans easily.

Your main SpringBootApplication class should be in `com.app` package
 and remaining classes should be in sub-packages.
Like `com.app.batch and com.app.api` are sub-package of `com.app`

By using this kinda package hierarchy you no need scanBasePackages.

Answer (score 0):

What is the package of the App class?

It needs to be in the base package so that Spring Boot Application scans all the packages inside it.

`@SpringBootApplication` annotation enables the following annotations/features on its own:

1. `@EnableAutoConfiguration`: enable Spring Boot’s auto-configuration mechanism
2. `@ComponentScan`: enable @Component scan on the package where the application is located
3. `@Configuration`: allow to register extra beans in the context or import additional configuration classes

For further details, you can read [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html)